# Did Turkey's president Recep Tayyip Erdogan ask "Trump towers in Turkey to remove Trump name in Istanbul urgently"?

Tags: turkey

The details section of this [November 9, 2016 YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKxjqeUr6N4) says:

> Turkish President Erdogan asking Trump towers in Turkey to remove
>   Trump name in Istanbul urgently

Is it true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes, but it wasn't as forceful as described, and his view has changed a lot in the past five months since this video was recorded.**

The Wall Street Jounal [reported in June 2016](http://www.wsj.com/articles/erdogan-wants-istanbul-towers-to-lose-trump-name-1466855822):

> ISTANBUL—Turkish President Recep Tayyip Erdogan called for Donald Trump’s name to be removed from a Turkish franchisee’s towers in Istanbul’s business district due to what Mr. Erdogan termed the presumptive Republican presidential nominee’s Islamophobia.
>
> Speaking at a Ramadan fast-breaking event Friday evening, Mr. Erdogan said an unnamed U.S. presidential candidate “has no tolerance for Muslims in America,” in remarks that have been taken to refer to Mr. Trump.

There is an inconsistency here between "called for in speech" [WSJ],  "asked Trump Towers" [quote in question] and "ordered to [ban]" [from YouTube description].

Since a failed coup against Erdogan, the reported position of the Turkish President has softened:

- [WSJ, October 2016](http://www.wsj.com/articles/trump-garners-unlikely-muslim-cheerleaders-1476967732):

> Mr. Erdogan’s tone, however, changed dramatically after the failed July coup against him. Unlike other Western leaders and the Obama administration, Mr. Trump refused to criticize the wave of detentions and dismissals in Turkey that followed the failed coup and expressed his admiration for the Turkish leader.
>
> Mr. Erdogan reciprocated and, in a September TV interview, played down Mr. Trump’s remarks on Muslims as mere campaign talk. Since then, the government-aligned media in Turkey have been remarkably favorable to Mr. Trump in their coverage of the campaign, while highlighting Mrs. Clinton’s support for the Kurds and allegations about her supposed ties with Mr. Erdogan’s current archenemy, Pennsylvania-based cleric Fethullah Gulen.

There's been further support from Erdogan since Trump's election win, e.g. [VOA](http://www.voanews.com/a/turkey-erdogan-trump/3589427.html), [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-election-turkey-erdogan-idUSKBN1343I8).